# Sign apk with keystore in different computer

Tags: android, keystore

I want another person to sign my apk and make uploads to Google Play. I have stored the keystore, so, just using the same keystore in the other computer (same alias?), will the other person be able to upload to google play? He's saying that he get an error of signature.

Comment: No , It should work in any computer , what error exactly showing post the screen shot..

Comment: As long as it's the same keystore, it should be ok

Comment: NO it work on dufferent computer but need which keysore that use before do sing apk and upload on play store

Answer (score 5):

If this is the same **key** (note, **key**, not **keystore** used matters as you can have different keystores really, but only single **key** is used for signing) on both computers and the same **key** is used to sign the app, then yes, it will make no difference who really signed the app. From technical perspective it matters that app is signed with the same key. Once this is done you or the other person will be able to issue update to Google Play with no problems. So in fact. it's wiser to  just share single **key** not whole **keystore**.

Comment: I've passed my keystore and he has signed the app opening that keystore and with the alias that I am using.

Comment: For security reasons you should just hand him single key (esported from your keystore). But it's up to you how you treat your security. Maybe it's just me being too paranoid :)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski what exactly do you mean by key, do you mean the password ?